# flask python make background thread while loop

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

i'm using a python flask app and after long fight with errors as i'm using sqlite3 database
when more than one user tried to commit a session at the same time it gave and error so i decided that users van only add and delete in the session but not commit it and i want to make session commit automatically at certain time let's say at 12:00
how to make a background task check for time and when it finds it's the provided time it commits the session ?
this is the current code for editing an object (as example) in session

```
@app.route('/NewRequest', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def NewRequest():
    connUser=session.query(User).filter(User.id==Session.get('user_id')).one()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        Types = session.query(Req_Type.id,Req_Type.Type_name)
        Pr = session.query(Req_Priorities.id,Req_Priorities.Priority_name)
        return render_template('NewRequest.html',conn=connUser ,name=current_user.name, items=Types,priorities=Pr)
    else:
        name= request.form['Name']
        Description= request.form['Description']
        Type = request.form.get('Type')
        Priority = request.form.get('Priority')
        newRequest = Requests(name=name, Record_Created=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), Description=Description, Assigned_To=None, Type_Name=str(Type), Priority_Name=str(Priority), Status_Name='Opened', User_ID=Session.get('user_id') )
        session.add(newRequest)
        flash('New Request With Name %s Successfully Created' % newRequest.name)
        UserRequests= session.query(Requests).filter_by(User_ID=Session.get('user_id')).filter(Requests.Status_Name!='Solved').all()
            return render_template('ReqData.html',conn=connUser , title='User Requests', rows=UserRequests)
```

i want to make a background task to check and if time is 12:00 it executes

```
session.commit()
```

is this way good or not ?
and how do you think this app would perform better ? would changing database (to postgresql perhaps) solve the concurrent commits problem ?
i tried using process to run background loop but it doesn't work, need it to be a thread

Answer (score -1):

not sure if it's efficient or not but for now it's working

```
def monitoring_loop():
    while True:
        if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")=="12:00:00":
            session.commit()
            print("Committed Changes")
            time.sleep(1)

monitoring_thread = threading.Thread(target = monitoring_loop)
monitoring_thread.daemon=True
monitoring_thread.start()
```

i still wonder about the other databases if someone can answer me i'll be grateful